Why are powers of a thousand the foundation for naming large numbers?
In our modern number system, large numbers are named based on powers of one thousand. For example, "thousand", "million", "billion", and so forth. Numbers in between these powers are named using combinations of smaller units, such as "hundred thousand" or "ten million." This structure also shapes how we write numbers, with commas or spaces separating digits into groups of three like this "184,684,565,120,443", this is almost universal across all countries in the word.
But why powers of one thousand? This is of course arbitrary. It could have been powers of one hundred or ten thousand instead. So who made this decision, and why? Was it a deliberate choice by a particular civilization or an ancient empire that stuck? Or did it emerge gradually as a practical standard, perhaps because powers of one thousand provide a balance since people might view 100 as too small and 10,000 as too big? Or because it is easy to read 1000 than 10000 without commas (I heard a theory of why Tally marks' five is different that is because one can identify the number of objects up to four without counting but at five it become more difficult so they change it maybe something like this happen here for the number 10000 because it consist of 5 digits and 1000 consist of four the maximum number)?

It is not universal – in India they use lakh (one hundred thousand) and crore (ten million).

Large byte numbers used to be named (and still are sometimes) based on powers of 2.

@WeatherVane Lets say it is almost universal since it is used in all of Europe, Africa, Middle east, Americas and Australia and most of asia

Perhaps it is a result of metrication and SI units. 1³ = 1 but 10³ = 1000.

@Jean-MariePrival But not as common since I never heard of this before

@WeatherVane if that so then the US wouldn't have used them :)

One kilobyte is 1024 bytes, 2^10.

@WeatherVane A good question is when did the use of powers of 1000 became universal and when did the use of base 2 became popular since I believe the use of powers of 1000 came way before the popular usage of base 2

Perhaps it is a linguistic result of the ease of speaking large numbers in groups. Obviously it cannot be ancient. The legacy was peculiar divisions such as 240 pence in 1 pound, and 112 lbs in 1 cwt, 60 minutes in a degree (hour), etc.

@pie I don't have time to research this in detail right now, but this system seems to originate (or at least was first described) in a manuscript Le Triparty en la Science des nombres by the Parisian Nicolas Chuquet in 1484. In it the author partitions numbers into six-digit slices, and assigns the terms byllion ($10^{12}$), tryllion ($10^{18}$), quadrillion ($10^{24}$), etc., the system still in use in non-English-speaking countries today.

The "milesian numerals" were the 27 Greek letters for the three orders of magnitude 1-9,10-90 and 100-900, so the greatest number was 999 and after that they had to repeat.

This is a rich and difficult question to answer in short form. But there are numerous extensive relevant expositions available that address the question. So rather than attempt, what would clearly be a deficient answer, I'll instead just add some critical comments to what others (njuffa, WeatherVane, sand1) have already suggested and then treat the topic as a reference request.
First off, I would agree with commenters that the notion of universality is difficult in this context. While $10^3$ is indeed widely adopted in Euro-centric influence. There is even deceptive similarity. For example billion in English ($10^9$) is not the same as billion in French and German ($10^{12}$)! French and German alternates -ion and -iard endings hence have million, milliard, billion, billiard for 3 digit tiers.
As njuffa already correctly pointed out, the system of tiering large numbers originally partitioned by 6 digits. This goes back to Jehan Adam in 1475 as by-million and as byllion by Nicolas Chuquet in 1484. For details see Flegg, G. et al (eds.) (1985). Nicolas Chuquet, Renaissance Mathematician: A Study with Extensive Translation of Chuquet's Mathematical Manuscript Completed in 1484. Reidel.. In French this was subdivided into 3 digit subdivisions in the 16th century. An example of the complication here is for example that the naming that today is used in German and appears very similar to the French was actually only adopted in the late 19th century due to war reparations. But given that billion does not mean the same in different European languages, and that the particular etymological traces differ within European languages should be a warning against assumptions of easy universals in this discourse. It may be important to differentiate between science discourse (English as lingua franca, leading to a certain kind of homogenization) and common day usage of number words and systems.
Sources that cover the topic of numbers, number systems, and number words:

Smith, D. E. (1923). History of Mathematics: General survey of the
history of elementary mathematics (Vol.
1). Ginn.
Menninger, K. (1969). Number words and number symbols: A cultural
history of
numbers. MIT
Press.
Ifrah, G. (2000). The universal history of numbers. Wiley.

This kind of work can go into quite some detail. For example, the detailed language use traces of the word million in English was covered extensively in the thesis by MacQueen:

MacQueen, D. S. (2010). The integration of MILLION into the English
system of number words: A diachronic
study.
Peter Lang.

